# Start midlet after installing

Tags: java, java-me, midp, j2mepolish

Is it possible to start a midlet automatically straight away after the user has installed it ?
So once the midlet is installed it launches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** it is not possible.

AMS installs the app, and then in most of the phone it will ask user for start app. we can't load automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible but you can achieve a slightly similar effect if you are able to make use of the midlet install notify in the jad

http://java.sun.com/products/midp/OTAProvisioning-1.0.pdf

then use push registry as your server would be notified that the application has been installed

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/questions/pushregistry/

One of the problems here is the signing model for permissions to allow for this to happen, you will probably need to look at Java Verified or similar

Answer (score 0):

At least on Nokia S40 devices, there is the manifest attribute Nokia-MIDlet-auto-start: http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-C5D3E0F5-72B9-4EE7-8BA7-20DE4A538FB8.html

Comment: But that attribute start's the midlet every time the phone is turned on ? I just want to start the midlet automatically once when the app is installed.

Comment: So store a flag and immediately close your app subsequent start ups.